# Резиновый DIV с круглым низом

Tags: html, css

Вопрос вроде простой, но поставил в тупик.

На макете резиновый блок с круглым низом, как сделать без js? (ширина и пропорции меняются!)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: через `border-radius` для низа

Comment: Снизу есть ответ с примером, можете посмотреть, почему это не сработает

Comment: При чем  тут вообще `js` и при каких обстоятельствах меняются и о каких пропорциях идет речь?

Comment: Пропорции любые, нижняя часть круг. Через JS. можно получить ширину блока и выставить бордер-радиус равный половине. Вопрос, можно ли сделать это через css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 0 0 50vh 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

нужному блоку просто `border-radius: 0 0 50vh 50vh ;`

Comment: Переместите код из codepen в текст ответа. А вообще автор уже разъяснил, что такой вариант ему не подходит

Comment: Andrey Ivasko, мистика какая-то) Почему это работает? vh - процент от высоты окна же?

Comment: Правильно! Автоматически подстройка под высоту) И не вытягивает. Вместе с бордер-радиусом дает магию

Comment: получится фигня, если высота экрана меньше половины ширины блока. Можно задать тупо `border-radius: 0 0 500px 500px` - чтобы радиус закругления заведомо был больше полуширины блока. Закругление при этом оной полуширины при рендеринге не превысит и будет все как надо.

Comment: Инквизитор, спасибо за дополнение, стало понятно в чем смысл. На всякий случай объясню тем, кто в поиске найдет и не понял - если border-radius двух соседних углов одинаков и превышает размер стороны элемента (не важно на сколько и в чем он задан) объединяющая их сторона закругляется по окружности с диаметром равному размеру стороны.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrap {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.div {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.div:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.div-1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.div-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

.div-3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
}

.div-4 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div div-1"></div>
  <div class="div div-2"></div>
  <div class="div div-3"></div>
  <div class="div div-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Border-radius учитывает и высоту тоже) Низ не круглый, к сожалению

Comment: Тут не все так очевидно(

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, но вариант выше изящнее и больше подходит